# How to write mapply results to file?

Tags: r, printing, mapply

I use mapply with a function "iter_group". This function return 3 values as list (I found that a list is the best way to return more than one value in a function) :

```
iter_group <- function(variable,index,time,status,tab){

... some calculations

#   out <- list(cutoff,HR,PV)  # <- this was the mistake
    out <- c(cutoff,HR,PV)     # <- gives the good dataframe output
    return(out)
}
```

The problem I have is to print the results returned by mapply. On the terminal the results "res" are displayed nicely but I did not manage to print them. I tried dataframe conversion, list printing, unlist().

```
res <-mapply(function(index{iter_group(variable,index,time,status,tab)}, iter_tab)

res <- as.data.frame(t(res))
colnames(res)<-c("cutoff", "HR", "Pvalue")
print(head(res))
print(typeof(res))

write.table(res, "outfile.csv", row.names = F, sep = "\t")

  cutoff           HR    Pvalue
1      0 3.023552e-07 0.2724982
2      0 3.018152e-07 0.2179909
3      0    0.6458174 0.6601571
4      0    0.9644801 0.9609625
5      0     1.195378 0.7573982
6      0     1.037754 0.9477343

[1] "list"

Error in .External2(C_writetable, x, file, nrow(x), p, rnames, sep, eol,  : 
  type 'list' indisponible dans 'EncodeElement'
```

The results are very well formatted on the terminal but we can see that typeof(res) = list in spite of data.frame conversion.

```
unlist(res) # does not solve the problem
res = as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, res)) # does not solve the problem
write(res, file="out.csv", sep = "\t") # does not print the results
lapply(res, write, "out.csv", append=TRUE, ncolumns=3) # does not print the results
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: typeof() returns the basic structure and dat.frames are list internally! class(res) shall give you data.frame

Comment: I think the problem is that every element of your `res` data frame is actually a list. I guess your output will be ok if your replace `out <- list(...)` to `out <- c(...)`

Comment: if I print print(class(res)) = [1] "data.frame" I obtain a dataframe, but write.table() does not print it.

Comment: out <- c(cutoff,HR,PV) in iter_group() solves the printing problem ! Thanks mt1022 !